# Make combinations (Lexicographical order) running in omp parallel in C language?

Tags: c, openmp, combinations

I need help. I couldn't get this combination generation algorithm (in lexicographic order) to work in parallel. The algorithm is taken from the Rosettacode site, the link is: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Lexicographic_ordered_generation

Source with added pragma omp parallel

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <string.h>

void comb(int m, int n, unsigned char *c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) c[i] = n - i;

    while (1) {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
        for (i = n; i--;)
            printf("%d%c", c[i], i ? ' ': '\n');
        }
        /* this check is not strictly necessary, but if m is not close to n,
           it makes the whole thing quite a bit faster */
        i = 0;
        if (c[i]++ < m) continue;

        for (; c[i] >= m - i;) if (++i >= n) return;
        for (c[i]++; i; i--) c[i-1] = c[i] + 1;
        
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char buf[100];
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        comb(5, 3, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Strange results are obtained with omp parallel.

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
3 4 6
3 4 7
3 4 8
3 4 9
3 4 10
3 4 11
3 4 12
3 4 13
3 4 14
3 4 15
3 4 16
3 4 17
3 4 18
3 4 19
3 4 20
3 4 21
3 4 22
3 4 23
3 4 24
3 4 25
3 4 26
3 4 27
3 4 28
```

I also tried embedding a filter, for example if I chose to skip a total of 3 numbers that are next to each other, with comb(7, 5, buf) to skip, ie. does not generate the specified rows.

```
1 2 3 4 5 - not to be generated
1 2 3 4 6 - not to be generated
1 2 3 4 7 - not to be generated
1 2 3 5 6 - not to be generated
1 2 3 5 7 - not to be generated
1 2 3 6 7 - not to be generated
1 2 4 5 6 - not to be generated
1 2 4 5 7
1 2 4 6 7
1 2 5 6 7 - not to be generated
1 3 4 5 6 - not to be generated
1 3 4 5 7 - not to be generated
1 3 4 6 7
1 3 5 6 7 - not to be generated
1 4 5 6 7 - not to be generated
2 3 4 5 6 - not to be generated
2 3 4 5 7 - not to be generated
2 3 4 6 7 - not to be generated
2 3 5 6 7 - not to be generated
2 4 5 6 7 - not to be generated
3 4 5 6 7 - not to be generated
```

I don't know if it makes the point, but comb(70, 45, buf) and skipping 4 adjacent numbers will save millions of combinations that are pointless and waste time.

I made many attempts at fixing the code, got nothing and gave up. Please help me to fix the code.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve (do you expect us to guess what are the "strange results with omp"?) but you have obvious race conditions on `c` (i.e. all the threads try updating it simultaneously)

Comment: Yes, you are right, competing threads, the question is how do I divide their work? If I make a "while" critical section, the point of parallel work is lost. I didn't think the strange result would matter.
1 2 3,1 2 4,1 2 5,1 3 4,1 3 5,1 4 5,2 3 4,2 3 5,2 4 5,3 4 5,3 4 6,3 4 7,3 4 8,3 4 9,3 4 10,3 4 11,3 4 12,3 4 13,3 4 14,3 4 15,3 4 16,3 4 17,3 4 18,3 4 19,3 4 20,3 4 21,3 4 22,3 4 23,3 4 24,3 4 25,3 4 26,3 4 27,3 4 28,

Comment: This task is poorly suited for parallelization, especially given the requirement to generate the combinations in a specific order.  In particular, in your approach, each iteration of the `while` loop carries deep data dependencies on the results of the previous iteration, so although one iteration and the next could run in different threads, they cannot run *concurrently*.

Comment: Of course it matters... Seeing how wrong is the output of a program can give clues about what is wrong in the code. When asking a question on SO, always copy paste (at least when possible) the error messages and.or the outputs. By the way, please edit your question to put the wrong output in it, rather than in a comment.

Comment: And about how to parallelize, I agree with @JohnBollinger: this code looks quite difficult to parallelize... Not all algorithms can be efficiently parallelized or parallelized at all. Sometimes, one have to go with a fully different algorithm for the same problem.

Comment: What you could try here is putting `atomic` directives for all accesses to `c`. `atomic` is much less costly than `critical`

Comment: Would it be acceptable to generate the combinations (in parallel) *in memory*, and then print them out serially?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the memory option is acceptable if done in parts, because for example comb(100,50, buf) is 100891344545564193334812497256 combinations, one combination of 100 bytes (in binary format).

Comment: In that case, I think you're hosed.  It would be possible to compute such large numbers of combinations in parallel if you did not need the results to be emitted in a particular order.  It would be possible to compute combinations in parallel and emit them in lexicographic order if the number to be computed were small enough to buffer a sufficient number of them in memory.  But without either of those, you can assign work to different threads, but I don't see how you could avoid serializing substantially all their actions, which would make parallelization moot.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Comment: You need to be able to generate the nth lexicographical combination to seed each thread with. As it stands, I don't think is a good fit for OMP.